# POST Body is not being sent with APIClient DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm fairly new to Django and have a solid background in `Laravel` (if you happen to make an analogy that would be awesome)

I'm trying to pass a body to an end-point and I'm not being able to do it.

I have tried:

```
fake = Faker('pt_PT')
fake.add_provider(company)
client = APIClient()


class CompanyPostTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.email = fake.email()
        self.username = str(fake.company()).split()[0]
        self.valid_payload = {
            'email': self.email,
            'password': '123',
            'username': self.username
        }

    def test_company_was_created(self):
        response = self.client.post('/v1/company/',
                                    self.valid_payload,
                                    # Also tried with content_type='application/json'
                                    format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

But when executing in debug mode the `response` object has `POST`inside `_closable_objects` with `QueryDict: {}` which I'm assuming no `body` is specified. Also the error message says `b'{"message":"You must provide a password"}'` which clearly shows the body is not being passed.

Via Postman I'm able to make the same request and create a `Company` without any problem.

Any idea would be awesome to solve such a problem.

**EDIT**
Also I have tried passing the `valid_payload` directly to `client.post()` like so:

```
response = client.post('/v1/company/', data={
                                   'email': self.email,
                                   'password': '123',
                                   'username': self.username
                               },
                               format='json')
```

Still not working after that

Comment: are you using `from rest_framework.test import APIClient` or?

Comment: @uedemir yes. I'm doing `from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient`

Comment: @uedemir Is it weird that in my `CompanyViewSet` I placed a `print("foo")` at the begining of the `create` method and it didn't print anything when I ran the test?

Comment: you are defining your `client` variable outside of the test case class. can you try `client.post('/v1/company/', data=self.valid_payload, content_type='application/json')` instead `self.client`?

Comment: yeah that's normal. because your serializer raise an error.

Comment: @uedemir I made a print inside of `Create` (`print(request.POST)`) and when I ran `python3 manage.py test` it printed `<QueryDict: {}>`

Comment: if you want to see posted data use `request.data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

client is not a part of `CompanyPostTestCase` that may cause the problem. Initializing inside function should solve the problem.

```
class CompanyPostTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.email = fake.email()
        self.username = str(fake.company()).split()[0]
        self.valid_payload = {
            'email': self.email,
            'password': '123',
            'username': self.username
        }



    def test_company_was_created(self):
        client = APIClient()
        response = client.post('/v1/company/',
                                    self.valid_payload,
                                    format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: I tried that but still giving me a `400 Bad Request` saying `You must provide password`

Comment: @Thedude just updated a bit, can you please try with this.

Comment: Still not working. I tried passing `valid_payload` directly to the client.post and its not passing the body for some reason

Comment: @Shakil, `setUp` method always run just before test methods which have prefix `test_`. why did you use like; `self.setUp()` and `return` in `setUp`?

Comment: @uedemir , yeah, no need actually. Not sure why this is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue recently, posting just in case it helps anyone in the same position as it was a pain to debug.

In my case it ended up being due to an incorrect JSON parser class being specified in DRF's `DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES` in the Django settings file. The solution was simply to replace it with the default DRF JSON parser (`rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser`).